# Java physics triangles

Tags: java, android, eclipse

okay, i cannot post images yet :/

Basically, i have an application with three edittext fields, three check boxes, a calculation button and a text field to output the answer. i want the program to scan to see which value is missing, so that from this it know which calculation it should do. Another method would be for the user to check one of the checkbox's and then the program would only run the calculation for the corresponding checkbox. 
for instance, if the user inputs Q = 10, T = 2, and checks the checkbox for I, the program would then do the math and display I = 20 ? 
this make much sense yet 
i spose in psuedo code it would look like 
" if checkbox one is checked and values for Q and T have been entered, then calculate value for I and display in answers field" however i will be adding some error checks and validation methods in there.
if you need the xml file and java file then please ask, im just looking for a method at the moment as to how i could do it, i wouldnt expect you all to waste your free time writing a whole program for me.
cheers guys and girls

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background1"
android:gravity="fill"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
tools:context=".CurrentPage" >

<!--
     The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc.
-->


<!--
     This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows.

-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Current_hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Welcome to the Current Calculation page."Hint - Use the check boxes to find the values that are missing "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Equation_letter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/current_calculate"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/current_calculate"
        android:text="     HELLO  "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Distances_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Equation_letter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Equation_letter"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/current_calculate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Q"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Q"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Q"
         android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:gravity="right|top"
        android:text="t ="
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/custom3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/t"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/custom2"
        android:background="@drawable/check_box_new"
        android:button="@drawable/check_box_new" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/custom1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/number_input_3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/custom3"
        android:background="@drawable/check_box_new"
        android:button="@drawable/check_box_new" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Current_hint"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Current_hint"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Equation_letter"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CurrentmainHelp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.31"
                android:text="HELP! This equation can be used to calculate the current of an object in amps. The correct equation to discover amps is I=Q/t. Where I = current, Q = charge flowing past a point in the circuit, and t = time taken for the charge to flow. Please note, Q is measure in coulombs and t is measured in seconds, with I being measured in amperes.

    Still need more help? "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Yes_Please"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.31"
                android:onClick="CurrentHelp"
                android:text="Yes Please"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/current_calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Calculate_Current"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_input_2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/t"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number_input_1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/number_input_1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_input_3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/t"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number_input_2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/number_input_2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/custom2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/number_input_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/number_input_1"
        android:background="@drawable/check_box_new"
        android:button="@drawable/check_box_new" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_input_1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Q"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/current_calculate"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Equation_letter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/I"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:gravity="right|top"
        android:text="Q ="
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/I"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Q"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Q"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Current_hint"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:gravity="right|top"
        android:text="I ="
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

okay, that was the xml, and this is the java so far

```
    package com.kieran.whetherfieldphysicscalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
// i=q/t this will be the first calculation on the list 



public class Current extends Activity {





        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_current);
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            setupActionBar();


          Button calc1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.current_calculate);

            calc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                 public void onClick(View v) {

                    EditText Charge1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_2);    
                    EditText Time1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_3);
                    TextView Distances_answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distances_answer);
                    double charge = Double.parseDouble(Charge1.getText().toString());
                    double time = Double.parseDouble(Time1.getText().toString());
        //Time is a class in Java
                    Distances_answer.setText("" +charge*time);

                }
            });
        }









    public void CurrentHelp(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CurrentHelp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

I am asking if there is an easier way to formate the program to find the values, rather than have to code each individual segment? 
cheers

Comment: Could u please post the code or attach the files..

Comment: I would have three text fields along with a button. When the button is clicked, each text field's text value could be checked against an empty string and thus you would know which field you need to calculate for. I would find it less intuitive to have check boxes for the user to choose which value should be calculated.

Comment: The only reason i thought to do the checkboxes is because im looking for something that is graphically different than just checking if the string is empty, essentially i want the program to tell the user if they have made a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I guess that you want the user to check only one checkbox and only answer corresponding to that checkbox should be displayed to the user.
so for that you would need to set OnClickListener on checkbox so that the corresponding operation is selected.
Read [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/) on how to set listener on checkbox and use it. Paticularly look for the addListenerOnChkIos() method as it has the code you want.
 Also set another OnClickListener on the calculate button and in that check which checkbox is checked depending on which you will perform the operation and update the textview.